# 0 bytes of shared 0 bytes (100%) used in Google Workspace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-compute-engine

I started using Google Colab through the GCE VM, but I have not been able to initialize or upload any notebooks.

The error I am getting is `The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota`, but upon looking into my Storage, I have 15 GB of available storage, `0 bytes of 15 GB used`.

Trying to fix it, I log in as the admin account and go to Storage, and then what shows is that `0 bytes of shared 0 bytes (100%)` and it is in red. So I believe the is something wrong happening with the storage allocation or the store quota?

The virtual machine was ran with 200 GB space, so I cannot see the issue.

Full error when trying to upload a notebook:

```
The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota
GapiError: The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota
    at YI.YA [as constructor] (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:1433:2101)
    at YI.iH [as constructor] (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:2270:222)
    at new YI (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:2334:151)
    at JGa (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:2396:348)
    at xa.program_ (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:2410:131)
    at za (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:21:57)
    at xa.throw_ (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:20:201)
    at Aa.throw (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:22:89)
    at c (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/456ec723e499489081e770703ac07ab8/external_polymer_binary.js:22:343)
```

I have not found a way to troubleshoot it or resolve it. There is nothing broken shown in the log, it says that its working as intended?

Comment: I have two Cloud Identity Free domain accounts using organization unit. They are both set up identically -- the only difference is account A was created years ago and account B was created recently. Account A's Google Drive allows me to use all 15GB of storage, but account B shows this dreaded thing: https://i.imgur.com/mvsfIIr.png -- this tells me Google changed their policy recently for Cloud Identity Free accounts.